# Error in profiling shared memory atomic kernel in Nsight Compute

Tags: cuda, profiling, atomic, nvidia, nsight

I am trying the global atomics vs shared atomics code from NVIDIA blog https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-fast-histograms-using-shared-atomics-maxwell/

But when I am trying to profile with Nsight Compute CLI, it shows an error for the shared atomics kernel.

```
==PROF== Connected to process 16078
==PROF== Profiling "histogram_gmem_atomics" - 0: 0%....50%....100% - 1 pass
==PROF== Profiling "histogram_smem_atomics" - 1: 0%....50%....100% - 1 pass

==ERROR== LaunchFailed

==ERROR== LaunchFailed
==PROF== Trying to shutdown target application
==ERROR== The application returned an error code (9).
==ERROR== An error occurred while trying to profile.
==WARNING== Found outstanding GPU clock reset, trying to revert...Success.
[16078] histogram@127.0.0.1
  histogram_gmem_atomics(const IN_TYPE *, int, int, unsigned int *), 2023-Mar-09 12:55:43, Context 1, Stream 7
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
    dram__bytes.sum.per_second                                                Gbyte/second                          13,98
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------

  histogram_smem_atomics(const IN_TYPE *, int, int, unsigned int *), 2023-Mar-09 12:55:43, Context 1, Stream 7
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
    dram__bytes.sum.per_second                                                 byte/second                        (!) nan
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ------------------------------
```

Why is this showing an error in ncu? For referance my main function looks like this:

```
#define NUM_BINS 480
#define NUM_PARTS 48

struct IN_TYPE
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

int main(){
    int height = 480;
    int width = height;

    auto nThread = 16;
    auto nBlock = (height) / nThread;

    IN_TYPE* h_in_image, *d_in_image;
    unsigned int* d_out_image;
    h_in_image = (IN_TYPE *)malloc(height*width * sizeof(IN_TYPE));
    cudaMalloc(&d_in_image, height*width * sizeof(IN_TYPE));
    cudaMalloc(&d_out_image, height*width * sizeof(unsigned int));

    for (int n = 0; n < (height*width); n++)
    {
        h_in_image[n].x = rand()%10;
        h_in_image[n].y = rand()%10;
        h_in_image[n].z = rand()%10;
    }
    cudaMemcpy(d_in_image, h_in_image, height*width * sizeof(IN_TYPE), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    histogram_gmem_atomics<<<nBlock, nThread>>>(d_in_image, width, height, d_out_image);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// not copying the results back as of now

    histogram_smem_atomics<<<nBlock, nThread>>>(d_in_image, width, height, d_out_image);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this showing an error in ncu?

The blog in question expects that the pixel (component) values will be expressed as floating-point in the range of [0,1.0).  This is why this kind of multiplication makes sense, for either the gmem or smem version:

```
  unsigned int r = (unsigned int)(256 * in[row * width + col].x);
                                  ^^^^^^
```

so this is not correct:

```
struct IN_TYPE
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

Instead, you want something like:

```
struct IN_TYPE
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

and make sure that you initialize those values (`x`, `y`, `z`) in a range of 0.0 to ~0.999999 max.

Based on the structure of the code, and as stated in the blog, I'm not sure that more than 256 bins makes any sense.  The code quantizes the `float` pixel values to an integer range of [0,255].

For the global data, your settings for NUM_PARTS (effectively the number of bins times the number of color components, or "parts" of each histogram) and the size of the output array don't make sense.

When I address those items, the code runs without error for me:

```
$ cat t2209.cu
#define NUM_BINS (256)
#define NUM_PARTS (3*NUM_BINS)

struct IN_TYPE
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};


__global__ void histogram_gmem_atomics(const IN_TYPE *in, int width, int height, unsigned int *out)
{
  // pixel coordinates
  int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  // grid dimensions
  int nx = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  int ny = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;

  // linear thread index within 2D block
  int t = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;

  // total threads in 2D block
  int nt = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;

  // linear block index within 2D grid
  int g = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;

  // initialize temporary accumulation array in global memory
  unsigned int *gmem = out + g * NUM_PARTS;
  for (int i = t; i < 3 * NUM_BINS; i += nt) gmem[i] = 0;

  // process pixels
  // updates our block's partial histogram in global memory
  for (int col = x; col < width; col += nx)
    for (int row = y; row < height; row += ny) {
      unsigned int r = (unsigned int)(256 * in[row * width + col].x);
      unsigned int g = (unsigned int)(256 * in[row * width + col].y);
      unsigned int b = (unsigned int)(256 * in[row * width + col].z);
      atomicAdd(&gmem[NUM_BINS * 0 + r], 1);
      atomicAdd(&gmem[NUM_BINS * 1 + g], 1);
      atomicAdd(&gmem[NUM_BINS * 2 + b], 1);
    }
}

__global__ void histogram_smem_atomics(const IN_TYPE *in, int width, int height, unsigned int *out)
{
  // pixel coordinates
  int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  // grid dimensions
  int nx = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  int ny = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;

  // linear thread index within 2D block
  int t = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;

  // total threads in 2D block
  int nt = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;

  // linear block index within 2D grid
  int g = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;

  // initialize temporary accumulation array in shared memory
  __shared__ unsigned int smem[3 * NUM_BINS + 3];
  for (int i = t; i < 3 * NUM_BINS + 3; i += nt) smem[i] = 0;
  __syncthreads();

  // process pixels
  // updates our block's partial histogram in shared memory
  for (int col = x; col < width; col += nx)
    for (int row = y; row < height; row += ny) {
      unsigned int r = (unsigned int)(256 * in[row * width + col].x);
      unsigned int g = (unsigned int)(256 * in[row * width + col].y);
      unsigned int b = (unsigned int)(256 * in[row * width + col].z);
      atomicAdd(&smem[NUM_BINS * 0 + r + 0], 1);
      atomicAdd(&smem[NUM_BINS * 1 + g + 1], 1);
      atomicAdd(&smem[NUM_BINS * 2 + b + 2], 1);
    }
  __syncthreads();

  // write partial histogram into the global memory
  out += g * NUM_PARTS;
  for (int i = t; i < NUM_BINS; i += nt) {
    out[i + NUM_BINS * 0] = smem[i + NUM_BINS * 0];
    out[i + NUM_BINS * 1] = smem[i + NUM_BINS * 1 + 1];
    out[i + NUM_BINS * 2] = smem[i + NUM_BINS * 2 + 2];
  }
}

int main(){
    int height = 480;
    int width = height;

    auto nThread = 16;
    auto nBlock = (height) / nThread;

    IN_TYPE* h_in_image, *d_in_image;
    unsigned int* d_out_image;
    h_in_image = (IN_TYPE *)malloc(height*width * sizeof(IN_TYPE));
    cudaMalloc(&d_in_image, height*width * sizeof(IN_TYPE));
    cudaMalloc(&d_out_image, nBlock*NUM_PARTS * sizeof(unsigned int));

    for (int n = 0; n < (height*width); n++)
    {
        h_in_image[n].x = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_in_image[n].y = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        h_in_image[n].z = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    }
    cudaMemcpy(d_in_image, h_in_image, height*width * sizeof(IN_TYPE), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    histogram_gmem_atomics<<<nBlock, nThread>>>(d_in_image, width, height, d_out_image);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// not copying the results back as of now

    histogram_smem_atomics<<<nBlock, nThread>>>(d_in_image, width, height, d_out_image);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

}
$ nvcc -o t2209 t2209.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2209
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```